# Criando objeto PHP a partir de HTML

Tags: php, html, framework

Imagino que os frameworks normalmente fazem o seguinte para criar um campo de texto simples:

```
$campoTexto = new CampoTexto("nomeDoCampo", "valorDoCampo");
$campoTexto->gera();
```

O resultado seria:

```
<input type="text" name="nomeDoCampo" value="valorDoCampo">
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, existe alguma classe/função que faça uma engenharia reversa do código acima? Imagino algo mais ou menos assim:

```
$tag = new ObjetoMilagroso("<input type=\"text\" name=\"nomeDoCampo\" value=\"valorDoCampo\">");
print $tag->type . " - " . $tag->name . " - " .$tag->value;
```

O resultado:

> input - nomeDoCampo - valorDoCampo

Comment: Muito interessante você poderia criar uma biblioteca com funções deste tipo para baixar NET.

Comment: Isso é possível com um *parser* de HTML (como [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)), mas tem certeza de que precisa disso? Não tem como evitar?

Comment: De uma olhada em processadores de xml, afinal html é um "xml", com sua tags e atributos

Comment: Existe algum objetivou ou é só curiosidade mesmo? Até é possível montar um framework de domínio específico, mas daria um certo trabalho.

Answer (score 4):

Com a [sugestão do Fernando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22592/criando-objeto-php-a-partir-de-html#comment41100_22592) cheguei a seguinte conclusão:

```
<?php
    $t = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"nomeDoCampo\" value=\"valorDoCampo\" peterson=\"bonito\" />";
    $html = simplexml_load_string(html_entity_decode($t));
    $arrAtributos = $html[0]->attributes();
    $nome = $html[0]->getName();
    print "Nome da tag: ".$nome."<br />";
    print "Atributos:<br />";
    foreach ($arrAtributos as $key => $value) {
        print $key." => ".$value."<br>";
    }
```

É uma sugestão simples ainda e precisa de ajustes, tipo:

A tag obrigatoriamente tem que ter fechamento como no XML (de novo, sugestão do Fernando):

```
<input> =  erro
<input /> = ok
<button></button> = ok
```

Não estou tratando erros.

Mas achei interessante pois acabou ficando "genérico" e soluciona meu problema.

Comment: Faltou a implementação da classe Milagre :)

Comment: kkkk, "de novo, sugestão do Fernando", nossa parece ser minha a culpa. Mas não sei no que você quer utilizar isso, mas é bem interessante, e para uma pesquisa posterior, (não conheço muito bem) mas acredito que validadores de html utilizam algo nesse sentido. Não sei se essa é sua implementação. Mas pode pesquisar para entender melhor como pode ser a sua implementação.